# AWS Codebuild: I want to use one project to run multiple repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

Whenever a Pull Request is created in a repository in code commit, I want to run a code Build on the same repo.
I have multiple repositories having PR's created for each and I want to use the single/same code build project to run the different repos, is that possible?
PS: I don't want to create 50 code build projects for 50 repo's it is difficult to maintain.

Comment: " is that possible? " - no, its not possible.

Comment: So, do I have to create a code build project for every repository?

Comment: It is possible to use single project for multiple repository. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-multi-in-out.html

Answer (score 0):

"is that possible?" - no, its not possible. As Marcin say.

That's why I use IaC.

I recommend that you search the AWS CDK.

You can manage 50 codebuild by for loop.

Like this.

```
var arr = ["codecommit1", "codecommit2", ..., "codecommit50"]

arr.forEach(repo => {
  new AwsCodepipelineCdkStack(repo);  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As Akshay Gopani suggested, CodeBuild supports that now I think: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-multi-in-out.html